# How to publish a tomcat webapp while running on port 8080?

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm running a `tomcat` on port `8080`, eg to access the manager application from local network only.

Now I'd like to publish a specific web application via `port 80`. How is this to be done regarding security?

Probably it's not suitable to just change the `<connector>` port to 80, as I then would also expose the manager and any other applications.

Question: is it possible to only allow access to a specific location on port 80? eg: `mydns.com/my-app/*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep `Tomcat` running on `8080` and use a reverse proxy on port `80` to route only what you want to the "inner" `Tomcat` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. I suggest you to use Apache server as proxy. You can read detail [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try configuring Apache2 Web Server. How to install and configure on Ubuntu is provided [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps)